# Can someone help me fix this program?

Tags: java, arrays, input, output, do-while

It was a correct syntax, and 100% works. but my lecturer **wants this syntax's works without 'break' Function BUT still use 'do-while' function.** Can someone help me? i'm stuck :(

Here's the code :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class NewClass {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] bil = new int[10];
        int x=0;
        while(x!=10){
            System.out.print("Input ke-"+(x+1)+" : ");
            bil[x]=input.nextInt();
            if(bil[x]==0) {
                x++;
                break;
            }
            x++;
        }
        System.out.println("==============================");
        for(int j=0; j<x; j++){
            System.out.println("Data ke-"+(j+1)+": "+bil[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not using do-while loop. You are only using while loop

Comment: can u fix the program? :( @Steephen

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class NewClass {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] bil = new int[10];
        int x=0;
        do{
            System.out.print("Input ke-"+(x+1)+" : ");
            bil[x]=input.nextInt();
            x++;
        }while(x!=9 && bil[x-1] != 0);
        System.out.println("==============================");

        int j = 0;
        do{
            System.out.println("Data ke-"+(j+1)+": "+bil[j]);
            j++;
        }while (j != x-1);
    }
}
```

Do while checks the conditions after the loop has run. So you can use them to break out of the loop.

I have changed the `x!= 10` to `x!=9` in the first loop, as the loop has to break after the x has become 9, otherwise the array will store 11 elements.

A similar thing has been done for the for loop.

If you want to know more, research more on how `do-while` is an exit controlled loop, and `while` is an entry controlled loop.

Comment: Try now @Ravi Widialvana, I fixed a logical error I had overlooked in the loop.

Comment: try it again. These problems with loop conditions should be things that you manage to get on your own.